# i havent been able to get test ethers from any ropsten faucet

Tags: ropsten

can anyone plz send me some test ethers on this address 0x2540faA5783D5347b2F622D599BdCA57034da31E
it would be gret help

Comment: Ropsten has been deprecated, Goerli is now the only Ethereum supported testnet. If you need any Goerli - https://goerlifaucet.com/. Solid dev docs to build - https://docs.alchemy.com/

Answer (score 0):

This faucet for ropsten is currently working: https://faucet.ropsten.be/